# jquery issue with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

As a step to learn jQuery, I am trying to create Sudoku, in which I generated numbers in div blocks from 1 to 89 (leaving 10 divisible numbers). My code works good in Google chrome but IE8 generates the div id's differently.

Please check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Mwb2E/3/)**

I highly doubt the error must be because of incompatibility of some methods of jQuery. The problem could be in the following steps:

```
var lastNumId = parseInt(_idGen.toString().substr(-1), 10);
var secondLastNumId = parseInt(_idGen.toString().charAt(_idGen.length - 2), 10);
```

In the above lines to do the same, I used different techniques because if I do so then it is working in Chrome.

Comment: If `parseInt` seems to be the problem try just using `Number(str)` or even `+str`, and see if that does it...

Comment: None of those are jQuery properties.

Comment: @elclanrs I used `var lastNumId = Number(_idGen.toString().substr(-1));`.. still same.. in IE8

Comment: @Juhana I changed it to methods. I think it is correct now.

Comment: Those have nothing to do with jQuery... they're plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a negative index in `substr` is not supported by IE until version 9.

Just use the modulo operator to get the last digit of the number. This works in IE8 also:

```
var lastNumId = _idGen % 10;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working.. I thought it doesnt convert string to int automatically.